# What's the best way to diagnose character encoding problems in Vim?

Tags: vim, encoding

This happens often if I open a plain text file in Vim. I see normal character text, but then � characters here and there, usually where there should just be a space. If I type `:set encoding` I see `encoding=utf-8`, and this is correct since I see smart quotes in the text where they should be. What are these � characters and how can I fix how they are displayed?

Comment: once text's been mangled by an encoding issue, it's hard to go back by simply changing encoding types.

Comment: Place your cursor on the bad char and hit `ga` to know what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`�` is the unicode replacement character. Whenever you use any UTF encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32), all illegal byte sequences for the used UTF encoding are shown as `�`. Other options are discarding the byte sequences or halting the decoding process completely at first sign of trouble.

For example, the bytes for `hellö` in ISO-8859-1:

```
68 65 6c 6c f6
```

When decoded with UTF-8, becomes `hell�`. `0xf6` does not ever appear in UTF-8 alone, but the other bytes are completely valid and "by accident" even decode to same characters.